# GalliumOS unmet dependency errors

Tags: linux, apt-get

I am trying to install Lasso server on Gallium OS using

```
sudo apt-get install lasso-instance-manager
```

and I am getting this error:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies: lasso-instance-manager : 
Depends: libicu52 but it is not installable 
Depends: libmysqlclient18 but it is not installable
Depends: libzip2 but it is not installable
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried a lot of things from google searches about fixing these types of errors, however, none seem to work. Some of the things I've tried are

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

All of the update seem to work fine, however, I'm still getting the unmet errors.

Comment: ? Did you add the "deb http://debianrepo.lassosoft.com/ " repo ? Old (2016), no Ubuntu versions, no packages for dependency http://debianrepo.lassosoft.com/

Comment: Yes, I have the repo added and I still receive the same unmet errors

Comment: The dependencies for those old packages are not available with your current OS. `libzip2` https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libzip2 ... `libicu52` https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libicu52/download ... `libmysqlclient18` may conflict, if any similar is installed https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libmysqlclient18/download

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fix for this. What did it was just manually installing the dependencies. I was able to find the deb packages in Ubuntu's archives. I then downloaded and installed all the missing dependencies and was able to get lasso server up and running.

Comment: You could have used apt to install them too.